# How to add icc color profile back to an image using rmagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, rmagick

I am using rmagick in rails and using 'strip' to remove all exif data but that also removes color profile from image. 
How can I add icc color profile back again to the image after strip.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the profile data in a file, use the [add_profile](https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#add_profile) method in the Image class. The documentation for add_profile also describes 3 other methods that may work for you.

Comment: I am trying to store the current profile data using color_profile method and then using strip! to remove all exif data after this I am adding color profile using profile!("icc", stored_profile) but again on checking color_prpfile I get nil